# Uncaught Syntaxerror while using html template

Tags: javascript, html, templates, underscore.js, parse-platform

I am using a html template and javascript to fill a div with a couple of Elements.

It all worked pretty fine until i tried to add an image to that template.

Now I'm getting following error everytime:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) underscore-min.js:1
w.template underscore-min.js:1
query.find.success Liste.js:89
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
r parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
w.each.w.forEach parse-1.2.8.min.js:1
n.extend.resolve parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
r parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
w.each.w.forEach parse-1.2.8.min.js:1
n.extend.resolve parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
r parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
w.each.w.forEach parse-1.2.8.min.js:1
n.extend.resolve parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
r parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
n.extend.then parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
r parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
(anonymous function) parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
w.each.w.forEach parse-1.2.8.min.js:1
n.extend.resolve parse-1.2.8.min.js:2
c.onreadystatechange
```

Edit: I looked witch line in underscore.js doesn't work and the error is in this line:

```
render = new Function(settings.variable || 'obj', '_', source);
```

My html-template is the following:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < wohnungen.length; i++)
                        { %>        
                        <% var wohnung = wohnungen[i]; %>

                        <img width="100px" height="100px" src="<%=wohnung.bild=%>"></img>

                        <div class="list-item" id="wohnung-"+'<%= i+1 %>'>
                            <div class="absolute-wrapper">
                            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>Anschrift</dt>
                            <dd><%= wohnung.strasse %></dd>
                            <dt>Miete</dt>
                            <dd><%= wohnung.miete %> €</dd>
                            <dt>Kaution</dt>
                            <dd><%= wohnung.kaution %> €</dd>
                            <dt>Flaeche</dt>
                            <dd><%= wohnung.flaeche %> m<sup>2</sup></dd>
                            </dl>
                            </div>
                        </div> 


                        <% }; 
            %>
```

And my Javascriptcode:

```
query.find({
          success: function(results) {
            var objects = [];

            // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                objects.push(results[i]);

            };

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 




                var bildurl = objects[i].get('Bild').url();

                wohnungen.push({strasse: objects[i].get('Strasse'), miete: objects[i].get('Miete'), kaution: objects[i].get('Kaution'), flaeche: objects[i].get('Flaeche'), bild: bildurl});

            };

            var templateString = document.getElementById('list_tmpl').innerHTML;
            $(ausgabe).append(_.template(templateString, {wohnungen: wohnungen}));

          },
          error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
          }
        });
```

The query is from the Parse.com API. I receive all the objects, and it worked until i added the image. I just didn't find any ) that appeared wrong to me.

I would really appreciate if anyone can give me some kind of solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` attribute in your image has a stray trailing `=`:

```
<img width="100px" height="100px" src="<%=wohnung.bild=%>"></img>
------------------------------------------------------^
```

That should be this:

```
<img width="100px" height="100px" src="<%=wohnung.bild %>"></img>
```

When you call [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template), it converts your template to JavaScript and then hands that JavaScript to `new Function` to get the compiled template, hence the location of your error. Your `<%=wohnung.bild=%>` ends up being converted to some JavaScript that looks like this:

```
__p += '' + ((__t = ( x= )) == null ? '' : __t) + '';
// bad syntax ---------^
```

That's not valid JavaScript so you get an exception from `new Function`.